# Place of N points with maximum distance from M points

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry, discrete-optimization

I have finite a rectangle in R² with M dots. I need to place N more dots in a way, that a minimal distance between each new dot and any of new dots, existing dots and corners of rectangle (basically, +4 dots) is maximal. Moreover, I need to place them inside the rectangle.

In layman terms I need to add dots to a rectangle with existing dots to make them spread as much as possible.

Additionally, I need to do this pretty fast (~10 million times per second, given the other things with dots are happens at speed of ~200 mil per sec). Are there any existing algorithms? Preferably fast and stable.

Comment: Are you interested in averaging the density?

Comment: Yes, something like that. As a very crude workaround I split rectangle into `ceil(sqrt(N+M))` equal subrectangles and check if there are any dots there. If no, I place one new dot in a each empty rectangle. Because there is only M dots, it's easy to see (pigeon principle) that some of those sub-rectangles are guaranteed to be empty. But it's far from perfect.